# Moderation bias against short answers

Tags: discussion, moderation

My answer to [this question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/33083/some-strange-moves-in-polgar-vs-najer-2009) was removed by a moderator for no apparent reason. While brief, it provided the correct answer to the question. I'd like to know why it was removed. Could it be that there is a bias against shorter answers?

Comment: I'd agree that there is a bias, since I find short, comment like answers distasteful myself, but I do agree with you that moderator removal is not nessecarily the right answer.

Comment: @RewanDemontay I'd say that "size doesn't matter" in this case. If a question can be answered with a short, direct answer, then that answer is preferrable to an unnecessarely wordier one

Answer (score 2):

Short, low quality answers are automatically flagged by the system. From there they go into a review queue. If two reviewers (or one mod) agree then the post is deleted.

[Here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/33258/advanced-video-chess-lectures/33269#33269) is an example which is halfway to being deleted as you can see from the comments and the timeline.

Comment: How does the system determine if an answer is "low quality"? The example you link shows an answer (chess24.com) to a question (where to find certain type of videos?)